# Could not establish connection to localhost:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have work on Hadoop/Hive. I have installed Hadoop 1.1.2 and Hive 0.10.0.When I use Hive as command prompt then it works fine,but when I am using as it JDBC in Eclipse then gives the below error :

> Could not establish connection to localhost:10000/default:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Answer (score 4):

You can connect to Hive in two modes. Through thrift server and embedded mode.
By seeing your **url localhost:10000/default**, it looks like you are trying to connect to the thrift sever. So please ensure that you are have started the hive thrift server by the following command.

```
    $ hive --service hiveserver
```

If you want to connect in embedded mode. you should give the url as

```
   jdbc:hive://
```

To use the embedded mode you should add the hive/conf and the jars in hive/lib to your classpath.

It is to be noted that, use of the Thrift server is not thread safe as of now.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more, I mean you said you are using JDBC to connect to hive.
If this is so, are you using **HiveMetaStoreClient** or something else.

Comment: @Charnjeet Perhaps the port 10000 is already in use by some other process. Please check that once.